# Is it OK for SEO to keep same URLs on new site without redirecting even though the site was down for a while?

Tags: seo, url, redesign

Is it OK to keep the exact URL from my old site into my brand new site without redirecting? Those pages had a 404 while the site was under construction.

I really not sure what's the best way.  I only had 5 pages in total on that site. The site's domain remains the same.

Comment: I assume you are saying that the previous 404 pages now have content?  If so, search bots will continue to crawl your previous URLs, and assume the 404 was temporary.  If a bot sees your redirect, it would also see that you now have content, so I don't see that there's much difference.

Comment: @Trebor "If a bot sees your redirect" - I don't think there is a redirect, or even needs to be a redirect (or even could be a redirect even if you wanted one), since the "site's domain remains the same". Same domain + same URL = same same. (?)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks All for your help, Google Webmaster community answered my question. I only need to make the URL's paths similar to the old ones to preserve the rankings and avoid broken links and redirect the new generated ones if they where indexed.

Comment: Just "similar"? Presumably you mean "the same".

Answer (score 0):

What you have asked is a bit unclear with respect of if the 404 errors were occurring on the new site (not great) or old site (irrelevant)

Long term thie latter should not be a major issue for your site, but short term it may reduce the number if pages Google returns and, I suspect, could lower the ranking (this is just an educated guess)

Comment: I think they mean that the 404s were occurring while they took the old site down and were still developing the new site.

Comment: Stephen Ostermiller, Correct mate that is what I was trying to say thanks.